Fault injection in Cadence Xcelium
I have a functional RTL simulation. I would like to check if bit flips at certain critical moments can cause errors in the circuit outputs. In the testbench, I can only manipulate external signals, but I am interested in flipping internal registers.
Can this sort of operation be done on Xcelium or similar simulation software?
I am interested in automating this sort of test and probing certain signals to observe (or not) modifications in the usual flow.


In the testbench, I can only manipulate external signals, but I am
interested in flipping internal registers.

This is incorrect.  You can also change internal signals from the testbench by scoping down into the hierarchy:
initial dut.cpu.signal = 0;

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 23.6 Hierarchical names.
To prevent the design from overriding the value, you should use the Verilog force statement.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 10.6.2 The force and release procedural statements
Here is an example of force/release.
Cadence also looks like it supports some type of fault simulation, but that is a broader topic.  Contact the vendor for more details.
